# Struggling to insert record into "SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database" from my C# WinForm Application. (I'm using VS 2010))

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my C# Winform Application I have written a code to insert record into the "SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database". Also I had debug code line-by-line everything is working fine (without any error) but after insert functionality when I checked my database I found that record is not inserted into the database, I'm strange why it is happening..!

But I think it is happening because, "when I tried to add database in my project I got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780444/struggling-to-add-existing-sql-server-compact-4-0-database-into-my-c-sharp-win)"  Following is my code to insert record into the database--

```
// Retrieve the connection string from the settings file.
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.snda_dbConnectionString;

//string conString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\db_snda.sdf";
try
{
    conString = conString +";Password = test@1;";

    // Open the connection using the connection string.
    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();

        // Read in all values in the table.
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_user_master" + "(user_id, password, user_type, user_title, first_name, middle_name, last_name, gender, dob, mobile_no, email_id, plant_code, div_code, region_code, reporting_to, releaving_date, created_date)" + " VALUES(@user_id, @password, @user_type, @user_title, @first_name, @middle_name, @last_name, @gender, @dob, @mobile_no, @email_id, @plant_code, @div_code, @region_code, @reporting_to, @releaving_date, @created_date)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_title", strTitle);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", strFirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middle_name", strMiddleName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", strLastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", strGender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_type", strUserType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plant_code", strPlantCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@div_code", strDivCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region_code", strRegionCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reporting_to", strReportingTo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", strUserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Encrypt(strPassword));  //Encrypt(strPassword)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_id", strEmailId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile_no", strMobileNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", strDOB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_date", strCreatedDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@releaving_date", strReleavingDate);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                           
        }

        con.Close();

        XtraMessageBox.Show("User Created Successfully.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        ResetAfterSubmit();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Thank you...!

Comment: I guess that Sql Server Compact Database is not for Winforms (it's for Web Applications), but you can work with it Using EF. Check this link http://erikej.blogspot.com.es/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

It is hapening because you mix up databases - the one you check is not the one that is used during insert as likely when you start the debugging of the program a copys created in the output folder - and then discarded when you stop the program.

This is not exactly a rare problem and a good indication of someone not using a search function to find a solution.

Comment: You are correct, But I have checked both .sdf files 1] One which is in my projects root directory and 2] in "Project/bin/debug/" but both are empty..!